# Generate a command block with variable data

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to `setblock` a `command block` with variable data in it. I want to make a variable sized array with an armor stand, and read a custom tag at a variable position. This position should be stored in a scoreboard as well.

Further information:

- Minecraft version 1.13.2
- Singleplayer mode

I've already tried this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:command_block{Command:{"text":"execute store result score posN replay run data get entity highfrequent Pos["},{"score":{"name":"#this","objective":"replay"}},{"text":"]"}} replace
```

But it doesn't work. It couldn't place the block, and I think I did something wrong with the JSON syntax.

***My objective is to have an array which I can read at a variable position.***

If anybody has an idea of how to do this, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: What's the actual error?  Hard for us to help you if you don't give us all the information.

Comment: Even if command blocks allowed JSON as their command, you forgot the quotation marks and square brackets around it.

Comment: It seems to me the title and your 'objective' (which I realize was constructed as an edit) do not really overlap a lot: could you rewrite the title to cover the goal of your question?

Answer (score 1):

The command inside a command block is a regular string, not a JSON component. Since there's also no way to convert a JSON component into a normal string, you can't use it as the command inside a command block.

Comment: What did you actually want to do with that? Maybe there's still a way to do what you want, but not with variable command blocks.

Comment: I try to make an array which I am able to read at an variable position.

Comment: So you mean just like the arrays in NBT? You can already do that, items allow arbitrary data in their `tag` NBT tag.